# could i save images in excel using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache poi excel api to generate reports. In some of my reports i need to provide small icons along with header labels.

Is it possible to save images in excel using apache poi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, POI is able to insert images into an Excel file. See the [POI Documentation on Adding Images](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images) for details

The support in POI for images has improved a lot over the summer, it's probably worth you trying with a nightly build until PI 3.9 comes out (soon!)

Comment: Thank you Gag - is it also available in GA releases?

Comment: Yes, but you may well hit bugs that have recently been fixed, so you'd be better off trying a recent nightly build. The code in question has had a lot of work on it in very recently!